# How do i configure Github to only send notifcations when I'am tagged

Tags: github

I have tried for 7 years to configure Github to only notify me:

- When I´am being added to a Pull request
- When a pull request I have responded to is updated
- When someone has reviewed *my* pull request
- Tagged in a comment

Nothing else.

Whatever I do I end up getting either too much or too little notifications. Feels like there something I'am not seeing. There are so many checkboxes :)
(I would prefer the slack github bot, but email also works)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same question. It wasn't obvious at first, but there is a way to set up a [Slack](https://slack.com/) integration.

1. Go to https://github.com/settings/reminders.
2. Search for `Scheduled reminders` in the navigator (`Integrations` section).
3. Click `edit` reminders for an organization (a pencil icon).
4. Authorize your `Slack workspace`. **Do not fill out the form below! It will be cleared after the space authorization.** It will write you a personal message in Slack from the GitHub Slack bot.
5. Set `Days`.
6. Set `Times` (multiple select is available) for a time zone.
7. **Check `Enable real-time alerts`**.
8. In the new list below pick your notifications from your PR/comment/mentions/assignments.
9. Create or update the reminder.

You can make a test run for the reminder if you have a pending PR. Just click a new button with a megaphone icon (near the pencil button).

Hope, this will help.